# Calculus Scholarship Problem

Tags: calculus

How do you go from line $3$ to $4$? I think that $-6c$ may be $A$, however I want to understand how to go from $\frac{960-6s}{-6} +c$ to $\frac{\ln(\frac{960-6s}{A})}{-6}$.

[image: Picture]

Comment: From line three to four, there is a constant $+C$ since we're integrating. Since $C = -\ln A$ for some $A$ we can use the identity $\ln(x) - \ln(y) = \ln{\frac xy}$ to consolidate the constant into the logarithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of the logarithm is : $(ln(u))'=\frac{u'}{u}$. $(1)$

You notice that : $\frac{1}{960-6s}=\alpha\frac{u'}{u}$, where $u=960-6s$ and $\alpha = \frac{-1}{6} $. Indeed $\alpha\frac{u'}{u}=\frac{-1}{6}\frac{-6}{960-6s}=\frac{1}{960-6s}$.

So with $(1)$, you have : $\int \frac{ds}{960-6s}=\int \alpha\frac{u'(s)}{u(s)}ds=\alpha \int \frac{u'(s)}{u(s)}ds=\alpha ln(u)+c=\frac{-1}{6} ln(960-6s)+c$. But if you write $c=\frac{1}{6}ln(a)$ id est $a=e^{6c}$, you have : $$\frac{-1}{6} ln(960-6s)+c=\frac{ln(960-6s)-ln(a)}{-6}=\frac{ln(\frac{960-6s}{a})}{-6} $$